# Como utilizar propiedades de otro modelo correctamente?

Tags: laravel-7

Buenas estoy intentando en un formulario de agregar contactos poder seleccionar con un dropdown a que cliente pertenece el contacto el cual estoy agregando.

Mediante a esta relacion: create_contacts_table.php

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('id_account');
$table->foreign('id_account')->references('id')->on('customers');
```

Donde el id de cuenta "id_account" de la tabla contacts (seria el id del customer) hace referencia al id de la tabla customers

Y en mi modelo hice esta relacion con eloquent: Contact.php

```
class Contact extends Model
{
    public function account(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class,'id_account','id'); 
    }
}
```

Y en mi vista por otro lado estoy intentando de cargarlo de esta manera,

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('contacts.store') }}" id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        @csrf
                    <div class="form-row">

                        
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="name">Nombre</label>
                            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        
                        
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="lastname">Apellido</label>
                            <input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="account">Cuenta</label>
                            <select name="account" id="" class="form-control">
                                <option value="">Seleccione el holding de la empresa</option>
                                @foreach ($customers as $key => $customer)
                                <option value="{{$customer->id}}">{{$customer->holding}}</option>
                                
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="position">Puesto</label>
                            <input type="text" name="position" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        

                        
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </form>
```

En mi contact controller llamo al controlador de customer mediante esta linea de codigo:

```
use App\Model\Contact;
use App\Model\Customer;
```

Y luego defino las siguientes funciones:

```
class ContactController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function view(){ 
        $allData = Contact::all();
        return view('backend.contact.view-contact', compact('allData'));
    }

    public function add(){ 
        $customers = Customer()::all();
        $contact['customers'] = Customer::all();
        
        return view('backend.contact.add-contact');
    }

    public function store(Request $request){
        $contact = new Contact();
        $contact->name = $request->name;
        $contact->lastname = $request->lastname;
        $contact->id_account = $request->id_account;
        $contact->idOwner = Auth::user()->id;
        $contact->position = $request->position;
        $contact->mobile_no = $request->mobile_no;
        $contact->email = $request->email;
        $contact->save();
        Session::flash('success');
        return redirect()->route('contact.view');
    }
}
```

Los errores que me saltan son 2, el primero que customers no esta definido, que seria la variable utilizada en el foreach para iterar todos los customers del dropdown, y el segundo error es el siguiente:

```
Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\Backend\Customer()
```

Pero no entiendo porque dice que no se puede usar ese metodo.

Comment: Esto *`Customer()::all();`* seguro es el origen del fallo, debería ser: *`Customer::all();`*

Comment: Y el otro error seguramente porque que no le estás pasando la variable a la vista en el return